# Is there any way to resize a image from a list based on file name using Firebase Resize Extension?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

Structure of my storage folder:
[image: folder dummy preview]

I want to resize the first image (`0.jpg`) only. I don't want to do any operation on other images of this folder.
Can I achieve this by using path like this `/rooms/*/0.jpg` in `resize extension`?
If no, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Resize it using what and in what programming language?

Comment: There is an extension called `Firebase Resize Image`. I was talking about that

Comment: Then yes, the [README](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/storage-resize-images) says you can use wildcards for the path. (Let me know if you have any further questions)

Comment: When I set this `/rooms/*/0.jpg`. Extension is not being triggered.

Comment: The path is for directories. Please read the `README.md` file, it's linked in [`Firebase Resize Image`](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-storage-resize-images) page.

Comment: Does it say that you can resize single image from a list of image in same directory?
I haven't found anything

Comment: It doesn't say that, that's what I'm saying, the path is for directories, not single images, any image uploaded gets automatically converted (and deleted if you choose that option). So if you only want to resize one image, you can chuck it into a folder specifically for resizing.

Comment: That's why I am asking the question. However Thanks for clearing

Answer (score 0):

For ease of reading I'm condensing the interaction in the comments:

The extension `Firebase Resize Image` does not have a way to directly resize a single image, it finds them through the use of directories. The path you establish for these directories can use wildcards, but cannot target single files.

For more information please view the [README file](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/storage-resize-images)